# Group checkbox and textfield arrays to display in form grouped together

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, forms, checkbox

How do i get 2 arrays to display grouped together after they submit form?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="location[1]" value="Chicago,IL"  />
<input name="qty[1]" type="text" size="8" id="qty[1]" value="500" />

<input type="checkbox" name="location[2]" value="New York"  />
<input name="qty[2]" type="text" size="8" id="qty[2]" value="100" />

<input type="checkbox" name="location[3]" value="Seattle"  />
<input name="qty[3]" type="text" size="8" id="qty[3]" value="200" />
```

so if the user select chicago and seattle, it would return like:

Chicago,IL - 500,  Seattle - 200

I have used this

```
$location = implode(', ',$_POST['location']);
```

which will display:  Chicago,IL, Seattle

But i need it to grab the "qty" also if the array is the same number. So it would pull in as:

Chicago,IL - 500,  Seattle - 200

The values for the "qty" will be user inputted

Comment: i dont know where to start

ive been using this


`$location = implode(', ',$_POST['location']);`

Answer (score 0):

Try with implode() function but first make and array from them.

Answer (score 0):

The thing to keep in mind is that checkboxes do not get sent to the server when they are not selected but the empty text boxes are, so a simple combination of `foreach` and `isset` will give you the desired result:

```
// Loop over all text inputs
foreach ($_POST['qty'] as $key => $value)
{
  // Check if the matching checkbox was checked
  if (isset($_POST['location'][$key]))
  {
    echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['location'][$key]) . ' - ' . htmlspecialchars($value);
  }
}
```

You'd probably want to add them to an array and `implode` the array to get a comma-separated list, but this is just a basic example.

Comment: this works out great!, now how would i get that to display in an email? this is how i had it when a user receives the email


`<tr valign='top'>
            <td>Location:</td>
            <td>$location</td>`

Comment: @user2405912 I would add the texts to a new array instead of echoing it. Then you can use the `implode` from your question on that array to get the string you need.

Comment: I just need to get it to print the same way in my email.... i had been  using `$location` to get my results before

Comment: @user2405912 See my previous comment.

Comment: i tried this `$location = implode(', ',$_POST[location]);`

but in the actual email it returned as this `Houston,TX, New Orleans, LA = implode(', ',Array);`

Comment: @user2405912 You need to use a new array and add the output of my example code to it instead of echoing it.

Comment: im not quite sure what you mean, i have your sample code working but i dont know how to change the array